# How to compare string inside an array from a text file

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm writing a code for an ATM project that reads a text file. The text file is written this format:

account number * name * pin * check balance *  saving balance

So, I pass it into a method that splits them into an array.

```
public void linesplitter (string line)
    {

     string[] split = line.Split('*');
        account = int.Parse(info [0]) ; 
        name = info [1] ; 
        pin = int.Parse(info [2]) ; 
        check = info [3] ; 
        saving = info [4] ; 
}
```

So, when the user enter the account number, it goes to a log in screen where they will enter the name and pin associated with the account number.

My question is how can I compare the name and pin with the account number?

Comment: What do you mean "compare"?

Comment: If the name and pin is associated or is the name registered with the account number

Comment: You'll have to store that information in a database and use queries to determine if the name and pin are associated with the account number. You could also use XML files.

Answer (score 1):

Sample for you.

```
 List<AccountDetails> accountDetails = new List<AccountDetails>();

        //Declare class to store your info
        public class AccountDetails
        {
            public String account { get; set; }
            public String name { get; set; }
            public String pin { get; set; }
            public String check { get; set; }
            public String saving { get; set; }
        }

        //This function is a just an example, you need to expand it to fit your solution
        public void linesplitter(String line)
        {
            //You can place your text file reader code here. 
            //And call this function from Page_Load.
            AccountDetails dtl = new AccountDetails();
            string[] split = line.Split('*');
            dtl.account = int.Parse(info[0]);
            dtl.name = info[1];
            dtl.pin = int.Parse(info[2]);
            dtl.check = info[3];
            dtl.saving = info[4];

            //Every line from your text file will store to the Global List as declare in 1st line.
            accountDetails.Add(dtl);
        }


        //this is the function that trigger by your Button Event.
        //Pass in parameters to this function to get account details.
        //So the output for this function, something like 
        //if(result == null)
        //  login fail. etc
        public AccountDetails GetAccountDetails(String AccountNumber, String Name, String Pin)
        {
            var result = (from a in accountDetails
                          where a.account == AccountNumber
                          && a.name == Name
                          && a.pin == Pin
                          select a).FirstOrDefault();                                               

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: I believe that he's a new c-sharper, so the linq to object statement will give him some trouble. Would you mind to simplify it, so everyone understands the code? This question would be especially for newer people.

Comment: Usually i don't direct provide the answer for new-comer, hope them can read into and write themselves. Btw, i just simply type some code as reference for him : )

Answer (score 0):

I prefer you to create a Class for account like the following:

```
  public class Account
    {
        public int account { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int pin { get; set; }
        public string check { get; set; }
        public string saving { get; set; }
    }
```

Then Form a List of accountObjects that includes all the account details from file where the account information ware stored. The iterate the list to check whether there is any matching credentials ware available or not. The code for this complete scenario will be like the following:

```
       List<Account> ATMAccountList = new List<Account>();
        foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines("your Path Here"))
        {
            ATMAccountList.Add(linesplitter(line));
        }
         int accountNumberInput = 123, pinInput = 6565;
        // This will be the input values from the user
         bool matchFound = false;
        foreach (var accountItem in ATMAccountList)
        {
            if (accountItem.account == accountNumberInput && accountItem.pin == pinInput)
            {
                matchFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (matchFound)
        {
            //Proceed  with account
        }
        else
        {
            // display error ! in valid credential
        }
```

Where the method `linesplitter` will be defined as Like this:

```
public Account linesplitter(string line)
    {
        Account AccountObject = new Account();
        string[] info = line.Split('*');
        AccountObject.account = int.Parse(info[0]);
        AccountObject.name = info[1];
        AccountObject.pin = int.Parse(info[2]);
        AccountObject.check = info[3];
        AccountObject.saving = info[4];
        return AccountObject;
    }
```

**Note :**

You can do the same by using **LINQ**

```
        if (ATMAccountList.Where(x => x.account == accountNumberInput && x.pin == pinInput).Count() == 1)
        {
            //Proceed  with account
        }
        else
        {
            // display error ! in valid credentials
        }
```

Comment: I believe that he's a new c-sharper, so the linq to object statement will give him some trouble. Would you mind to simplify it, so everyone understands the code? This question would be especially for newer people.

Comment: @Jannik: I have updated the answer with condition checking inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

Create a class to store all the account information. As you read the line, create instance of that class and fill up the info and store in the List. Now to compare name and pin you can just use Linq query.

```
  Class AccountInfo
    {
     public int AccountNumber {get;set;}
     public string Name {get;set;}
     public int AtmPin {get;set;}
    public string Check {get;set;}
    public string Saving {get;set;}
    }

  //  Now in your Main program, use that class like this
    List<AccountInfo> accountInfoList= new List<AccountInfo>();
    foreach(string line in File.ReadAllLines("filename"))
    {
       AccountInfo ai =new AccountInfo();
      string[] split = line.Split('*');
            ai.AccountNumber = int.Parse(info [0]) ; 
            ai.Name = info [1] ; 
            ai.AtmPin = int.Parse(info [2]) ; 
            ai.Check = info [3] ; 
            ai.Saving = info [4] ; 
           accountInfoList.Add(ai);
    }

    // Some code to accept name and pin from user

    // Now compare name and pine like this

    var validationSuccessful = accountInfoList.Any(x=>x.AccountNumber==userEnteredAccountNumber &&
                        x.Name==userEnteredName &&
                        x.AtmPin==userEnteredPin);

    if(validationSuccessful)
    // Display next screen
    else
    // Display message log in failure
```

Please keep in mind this is simplest approach. I am assuming you are working on some practice project..Real ATM Project will have lot of security and will do comparison of Pin using Salt and Hash mechanism. It will definitely have some database or service.

As Jannik suggested, this is how you could do comparison without Linq query

```
bool validationSuccessful=false;

foreach(AccountInfo accountInfo in AccountInfoList)
{
  if(accountInfo.AccountNumber==userEnteredAccountNumber &&
                            accountInfo.Name==userEnteredName &&
                           accountInfo.AtmPin==userEnteredPin)
       {
        validationSuccessful = true;
         break;
       }
}
```

Comment: I believe that he's a new c-sharper, so the linq to object statement will give him some trouble. Would you mind to simplify it, so everyone understands the code? This question would be especially for newer people

Comment: @Jannik updated code to do comparison in simple way but you should always choose code which is optimal...so I am keeping Linq query code as well

Comment: @un-lucky Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 0):

As an option, you must gather all information from text file into collection of wrapper class instances, and then after user enteres account number, you find an item in your collection by number, and if such item exists, you expect the desired pin and name, make your validation checks, and etc...

For example you create class:

```
class AccountInfo
{
    public long AccountNumber { get;set; }
    public int Pin { get;set; }
    public string Name { get;set; }
    public string Check { get;set; }
    public string Saving { get;set; }
}
```

And convert yout text data into collection of items:

```
var textLines = sourceTextData.Split('\r\n').ToList();
var accountsCollection = textLines.Select(i => 
new AccountInfo
{ 
  AccountNumber = Convert.ToDouble(i.Split('*')[0]),
  Pin = Int32.Parse(i.Split('*')[1]),
  Name = i.Split('*')[2],
  Check = i.Split('*')[3],
  Saving = i.Split('*')[4]
}).ToList();
```

Or instead of a list you can prepare a dictionary, where Dictionary keys will be account numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic Console Application that might give you some ideas....

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    //private static XElement AccountData = new XElement("Root");
    private static DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(@"<Path to your account data file>\AccountData.txt");
        string strAccountNumber = string.Empty;
        string strPin = string.Empty;
        string strName = string.Empty;

        dataSet.ReadXml(new StringReader(new XElement("Root",
                            from str in readText
                            let fields = str.Split('*')
                            select new XElement("AccountData",
                                new XAttribute("AccountNo", fields[0]),
                                new XAttribute("Name", fields[1]),
                                new XAttribute("Pin", fields[2]),
                                new XAttribute("ChkBalance", fields[3]),
                                new XAttribute("SavBalance", fields[4])
                            )
                        ).ToString()));

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your Account Number (press 'Q' to exit)");
            strAccountNumber = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

            if (dataSet.Tables[0].Select(string.Format("AccountNo = '{0}'", strAccountNumber)).Count() == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter your Pin");
                strPin = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter your Name");
                strName = Console.ReadLine();

                if (dataSet.Tables[0].Select(string.Format("Pin = '{0}' AND Name = '{1}'", strPin, strName)).Count() == 1)
                {
                    DataRow[] result = dataSet.Tables[0].Select(string.Format("Pin = '{0}' AND Name = '{1}'", strPin, strName));
                    foreach (DataRow row in result)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Account Info for :: {0}", strName));
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}", row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Details");
                }
            }
        } while (strAccountNumber != "q");
    }
}
}
```

Don't forget the replace the path in.....

```
string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines ....
```

with the path to your data.....